# Are there functions like timedMovingAverage in CnosDB?

Tags: cnosdb

I wrote some BTC data into CnosDB by Telegraf. And i did some query like this.[image]

Obviously, I got the answer. But the query-sql is too long.
So, I want to know are there functions to make my job easier?